# Javascript two datepicker conflict

Tags: javascript, datepicker

Here is my code complete code:

```
<!doctype html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Date Picker</title>
</head>
<body>
<strong>Departing:</strong><br/>
<select name='dateSingleMonthDeparting' onChange='changeDate(this.options[selectedIndex].value);'>
    <option value='na'>Month</option>
    <option value='1'>January</option>
    <option value='2'>February</option>
    <option value='3'>March</option>
    <option value='4'>April</option>
    <option value='5'>May</option>
    <option value='6'>June</option>
    <option value='7'>July</option>
    <option value='8'>August</option>
    <option value='9'>September</option>
    <option value='10'>October</option>
    <option value='11'>November</option>
    <option value='12'>December</option>
</select>
<select name='dateSingleDayDeparting' id='day'>
    <option value='na'>Day</option>
</select>
<select name='dateSingleYearDeparting' id='year'>
    <option value='na'>Year</option>
</select><br/>



<strong>Returning:</strong><br/>
<select name='dateSingleMonthReturning' onChange='changeDate(this.options[selectedIndex].value);'>
    <option value='na'>Month</option>
    <option value='1'>January</option>
    <option value='2'>February</option>
    <option value='3'>March</option>
    <option value='4'>April</option>
    <option value='5'>May</option>
    <option value='6'>June</option>
    <option value='7'>July</option>
    <option value='8'>August</option>
    <option value='9'>September</option>
    <option value='10'>October</option>
    <option value='11'>November</option>
    <option value='12'>December</option>
</select>
<select name='dateSingleDayReturning' id='day'>
    <option value='na'>Day</option>
</select>
<select name='dateSingleYearReturning' id='year'>
    <option value='na'>Year</option>
</select>



<script>
function changeDate(i){
    var e = document.getElementById('day');
    while(e.length>0){
        e.remove(e.length-1);
        var j=-1;
        if(i=="na"){
            k=0;
        }else if(i==2){
            k=28;
        }else if(i==4||i==6||i==9||i==11){
            k=30;
        }else{
            k=31;
        }
    }
    while(j++<k){
        var s=document.createElement('option');
        var e=document.getElementById('day');
        if(j==0){
            s.text="Day";
            s.value="na";
            try{
                e.add(s,null);
            }catch(ex){
                e.add(s);
            }
        }
        else{
            s.text=j;
            s.value=j;
            try{
                e.add(s,null);
            }catch(ex){
                e.add(s);
            }
        }
    }
}
var currentTime = new Date();
y = currentTime.getFullYear()+1;
while (y-->1909){
    var s = document.createElement('option');
    var e = document.getElementById('year');
    s.text=y;
    s.value=y;
    try{
        e.add(s,null);
    }catch(ex){
        e.add(s);
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have two datepickers. When I change the first one it works perfectly, but if I change the second one the functions will work in the first datepciker

I want them to have their own function for each datepicker. What will I do to make this happen? I already tried to make put something like this `getElementById('day day2')` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `select` have assigned the ids `day` and `year` twice in your markup. That is wrong. ID should be unique.

Please change those IDs to day1, year1, day2 and year2. Then pass those ids as parameters into the function like this `changeDate(this.value, "day1", "year1")` and this `changeDate(this.value, "day2", "year2")`.

Now define changeDate as

```
function changeDate(i, day, year) {
    var e = document.getElementById( day ); // please note that day is the variable passed

    ...................
}
```

As an unrelated side note, `this.options[selectedIndex].value` is same as `this.value`

Comment: ok everything is working fine now, but the problem is the year. there are no option on the year

Comment: change `var e = document.getElementById('year');` to `var e = document.getElementById( year );` year is a variable now

Comment: I already tried that but it's still the same. I can't find the problem. Thank you by the way =)